# awk is printing lines twice when only one print command is used

Tags: awk

My awk script is printing each line twice. How do I stop it from printing the first of two duplicate lines?

csv data:

```
Num,Type,Score,Height
1,rock,10,11
2,leaf,6,99
3,bleach,8,9
4,koch,1,0
5,bleach,19,19
6,korn,10,12
7,batman,99,10
8,leaf,6,7
```

awk script:

```
FS = ","
BEGIN{
    good = 10
}
{
    color = ($3 >= good ? 32 : 31)
    $3="\x1b["color"m"$3"\x1b[0m"
    print
}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Looking at your script it doesn't look like it should print the result twice. I'm not aware around the result but if you want to print one time per line, you can try a simple `if` statement

Comment: `FS = ","` is an assignment which will always evaluate to 'true' and since there's no `{...}` action block associated with it then the default behavior is to print the current line; as @MyICQ has pointed out - move the `FS = ","` inside the `BEGIN {...}` block

Comment: Is the 2nd line of output you show REALLY missing the `Nu` from the start of `Num`? If so do you know why? It might be the issue described at [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

default action is print, and then you add another rule with specific print line.

A simple correction is

```
BEGIN{
    FS = ","
    good = 10
}
{
    color = ($3 >= good ? 32 : 31)
    $3="\x1b["color"m"$3"\x1b[0m"
    print
}
```

You can see the default by executing this script, which still prints all lines.

```
FS=","
```